# Why does C++ not allow variadic parameters in a non-template function?

Tags: c++, overloading, variadic-functions

```
int foo(int i)
{
    return i;
}

int foo(int i, int... n)
{
    return i + foo(n...);
}

int main()
{
    return foo(1, 2, 3); // error
}
```

Why does C++ not allow such an intuitive syntax?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments

Comment: @LarsNielsen i doubt it, I think he wants a type-safe solution.

Comment: Because it has a name already, that is either `std::array` or `std::vector` or `std::list` ot _iterators abstraction_ and so on?

Answer (score 6):

You need the template mechanism to instantiate your second `foo` function, since the signature of the function is only determined when it's used. So the only feature you could ask for here, is that your syntax implies a function template where the template parameter pack is constrained to type `int`.

There is considerable opposition to templates that don't have the template keyword, though. However, things will change in that regard with the Concepts TS.

Comment: In C, it's perfectly legal to write `int foo(int i, int n, ...);`. C's variadic arguments are passed at runtime, and are constrained to one type. (`int` in this case)